# Searching for a String on $location change in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does Angularjs provide any method that can traverse the DOM for text after a new view is returned? The [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) seems to almost accomplish this but I'm not looking to return a new array of elements. For example;

html

```
<div ng-view="">
    <ul>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Eggs</li>
        <li>Cheese</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', { templateUrl: 'example.html' })
    }]);
    app.controller('rttController', function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
        // Search through the DOM for text returned in this view
    });
});
```

My end goal is to have an array of predefined keywords that I'd be searching for in the DOM:

`var foods[] = {"yogurt", "butter", "margarine"}` .

Any ideas?

Comment: `array of keywords` can you give example for this

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't provide this functionality. Is it not possible to load the variables into an array and loop through that. The using `ng-repeat` you can display them on the page in your list.

Are you limited to having these items in HTML or would you be able to load them into an array and display them?

Maybe you could look into child scopes and having a controller within the HTML file you are including to manage the list?

Comment: Thanks @SM3RKY, I unfortunately am tied to what is rendered in the HTML. Basically any of the keywords that exist on the page would get highlighted after Angular returns a new dynamic view. I'll look into having a child Controller on the 2nd file & see what I can come up with.